# Display image in circular shape from external storage

Tags: flutter

I have tried following code snippet:

```
new Container(
    height: 80.0,
    width: 80.0,
    decoration: new BoxDecoration
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
    border: Border.all(color: const Color(0x33A6A6A6)),
    // image: new Image.asset(_image.)
    ),
    child: new Image.file(_image),
));
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 11):

You can try either the [BoxDecoration](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html) class with a Radius of 50:

```
new Container(
    height: 80.0,
    width: 80.0,
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        color: const Color(0xff7c94b6),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(50.0)),
        border: Border.all(color: const Color(0xFF28324E)),
    ),
    child: new Image.file(_image)
),
```

the [CircleAvatar](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/CircleAvatar-class.html) class:

```
new CircleAvatar(
  backgroundColor: Colors.brown.shade800,
  child: new Image.file(_image),
),
```

or more specifically your code is missing a `(` after BoxDecoration and has to many `)`.

So with the [BoxShape](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/BoxShape-class.html) class:

```
new Container(
  height: 80.0,
  width: 80.0,
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
    border: Border.all(color: const Color(0x33A6A6A6)),
    // image: new Image.asset(_image.)
  ),
  child: new Image.file(_image),
),
```

Comment: I have a File object that contains the path of image. Above solution is not working.

Comment: <br/>new Container(<br/>
              height: 80.0,<br/>
              width: 80.0,<br/>
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(<br/>
                color: const Color(0xff7c94b6),<br/>
                image: new DecorationImage(<br/>
                  image: new ExactAssetImage(_image.path),<br/>
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,<br/>
                ),<br/>
                border: Border.all(color: const Color(0xFF28324E)),<br/>
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(50.0)),<br/> 

              ),
            )

Comment: The code your posted initially was missing a bracket. I edited the post to include the `BoxDecoration` with the `BoxShape` class.

Answer (score 8):

here you can do like this to set placeholder image and picked image from camera/gallery

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () => onProfileClick(context), // choose image on click of profile
  child: Container(
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        image: DecorationImage(
            image: profilePhoto == null  //profilePhoto which is File object
                ? AssetImage(
                "assets/images/profile_placeholder.png")
                : FileImage(profilePhoto), // picked file
            fit: BoxFit.fill)),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a local image from asset then you can use CircleAvatar as,

```
CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: ExactAssetImage('assets/images/cook.jpeg'),
              // Optional as per your use case
              // minRadius: 30,
              // maxRadius: 70,
            ),
```

If you are using a network image then you can use CircleAvatar as,

```
CircleAvatar(
         radius: 30.0,
         backgroundImage: NetworkImage(imageURL),
         backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
         ));
```

Comment: And what about, if you want to load the image from Assets folder?

Comment: Also any Placeholder while the image is being fetch from the network?

Answer (score 3):

Add new Circle Avatar and it 's have a child add in it your image and you have radius

```
new CircleAvatar(
  child:new Image.asset("Your Directory"),
  radius: 60.0
)
```

Answer (score 3):

for me this worked (having a file instead of an asset or network image)

```
 Container(
     height: 150.0,
     width: 150.0,
     decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
      ),
      child: ClipRRect(
             borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(75.0),
             child: (image != null)
             ? new Image.file(image): Container(),
             ),),
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.5

Image.file(_image).image will convert to ImageProvider then it can be used external image in BoxDecoration directly.

```
File _storedImage;
     :
     :

Widget _localImageFromCamera() {
  return Container(
    height: 80.0,
    width: 80.0,
    decoration: BoxDecoration
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
         border: Border.all(color: const Color(0x33A6A6A6)),
         image: DecorationImage(image: Image.file(_storedImage).image, fit: BoxFit.cover),
    ),
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ClipRRect`  worked fine for me hope help you too

```
  ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
              child:Image.network(
                _supplierProduct.productImage,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                height: 220,
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Container(
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: NetworkImage('assets/logo.png'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(100.00)),
            ),
          ),
```